# Subsetting based on multiple conditions in R

Tags: r

I would like to subset my data based on two conditions: if X is blank and if Y is blank.

Subsetting based on 1 condition is:

```
Blank_X <- Q4[is.na(Q4$X),]
```

How do I add a second condition to this?

Comment: try ```Blank_X <- subset(Q4,is.na(Q4$X) & is.na(Q4$Y))```

Comment: or `Blank_X <- Q4[is.na(Q4$X) & is.na(Q4$Y),]`

Comment: .. where the logical AND is denoted as `&` and the logical OR is denoted `|`. Be wary that R also knows `&&` and `||` which are similar but noch the same. There is also `!` for logical NOT and `xor` which is set in text, not as symbol. Find out more by typing `help("&")` in your R console.

Comment: @TusharLad and GKi : Please put your answers in as an answer, not as a comment so that the OP can accept an answer and the question is marked as answered and accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `&` (and) to combine multiple conditions.

```
Blank_X <- Q4[is.na(Q4$X) & is.na(Q4$Y),]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way with `subset`

```
Blank_X <- subset(Q4,is.na(Q4$X) & is.na(Q4$Y))
```

with filter

```
Blank_X  <- Q4 %>% filter(X!= NA & Y!=NA)
```